# Changes done on EC2 instance are getting very slowly reflected

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a website on an EC2 instance, everytime I do a change in the code of my website which is present on the instance and save it, the changes are getting reflected in 15-20 min on the website.

Can anyone tell me why the changes are getting reflected so slowly on my website ?

Comment: Is it possible that your website is cached somewhere (e.g. browser) ?

Comment: After doing changes to my website I empty the cache of browser and than open my website, but still the same results :(

Comment: Does your website on IIS, Apache or ????

Comment: Website is on Apache server

Comment: Not even a single AWS member have answer to my question ?

Answer (score 2):

i would also go through the cache (in some way) hint.

What you can do is to try that :

a) on your server modify a non important file already existing (not a new one). Be Carefull to make some changes that will also modify the size (adding a part of content should be enough).

b) from your server using ssh run the following command :
curl -v -x 127.0.0.1:80 'http://yoursite.com/your-modified-file.html'

c) Note from the output the following values :

- ETAG
- CACHE-CONTROL
- Last Modification Time
- Content size

d) From an external computer (the oen where you are thinking the changes are reflected slowly) reapeat step b)

e) repeat step c) with the output of d)

f) if any of the values are different, this will be the proof of caching system (CDN, reverse proxy, proxy, browser local cache ....)

NB: Are you sure you are getting content directly from your server and you have not enabled cloudfront ? you can check matching the ips in the web server logs.

Comment: I used following command curl -v -x 127.0.0.1 'http://yoursite.com/your-modified-file.html', I am getting following error curl: (7) couldn't connect to host curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: No I have not enable cloudfront, I am directly getting the content from my server

Comment: Sorry incomplete command you should try : curl -v -x 127.0.0.1:80 'http://yoursite.com/your-modified-file.html'